# Python.Ошибки при подключении библиотеки googletrans

Tags: python, macos, google-translate

Натыкался на подобные ошибки в stackoverflow, но ни одно решение так и не помогло.
Версия Python 3.8.5
Версия googletrans 3.0.0.
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

```
from googletrans import Translator 
translator = Translator() 
file = open('dict_orig', 'r') #dict_orig - файл в директории проекта 
text = file.read()
res = translator.translate(text, dest='en')
print(res.text)
```

Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Версия googletrans 3.0.0 имеет баги, мне помогло обновление до альфа-версии.

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка выводится, потому что не находится содержимое файла. В коде не указан полный путь к файлу.
Укажи полный путь,например С:\user\Desktop\dict_orig

Comment: Спасибо, но файл лежит в директории проекта, и даже если указывать абсолютный путь - ошибка остается.